# OpenCV 4.1 native Videocapture on Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv

OpenCV 4.1 [release notes](https://opencv.org/opencv-4-1/) state that *Android Media NDK API support has been added to videoio module*.

However, i still fail to open the camera on an Android smartphone using Videocapture.open(). I know that in the past, the Android NDK did not provide a native camera interface (changed in Android 7.0 Nougat / API level 24) and cv::Videocapture was therefore not supported on Android prior to OpenCV 4.1.
Unfortunately, i could not find detailed patch notes on what exactly was added in the 4.1 release.

I use OpenCV as a .so library / plugin within Unity3D, which handles the camera permissions (tested - permission is granted).

Has anyone had success with this and can point me in the right direction?